# Mysql Performance: IP direct as BINARY or via reference

Tags: mysql, performance, ip

I have a log in a Table, which gains at 420000 entrys per month. I need to check many of these entrys ofen, so select should run fast on this table. All vaules in these table are int(4) except a IP Addrese which is a Binary(4).

It is better to create an extra IP-Table and only store a id for the ip in the log table or is  BINARY comparison so fast how INTs compare?

Answer (score 0):

IPv4 number is actually interchangeable with int, which means that you can convert int to IP address and vice versa with no data loss (int is 4 bytes long). So you shouldn't really need this additional table with "ids".

To answer your main question: storing IP as int should be faster - you may perform tests on you own and gather exact statistics.

Having said that I have few doubts about your data model. First thing is whether you're storing Internet IP addresses? If so, you should consider storing IPv6 addresses also. Another thing is that you mentioned that you will often query this table (expecting selects to run fast) and at the same time insert ~233 records per minute. I don't know which engine you are going to use, but with InnoDb that might not work - you will run into issues with locks. One way to avoid that is to partition your data based on time and query partitions which are not currently in use. Be careful also with indexes as having many of them will slow down your inserts. You may also have a seperate table for inserts and partitioned index-heavy table for selects. You could move data among them at the time when your insert rate is low. What do you think?